# How do I get rid of extra images in my Processing animation?

Tags: animation, processing

Language:  Processing 3.2.1

I have an animation that should drop vertical lines over a background from the top of the screen to the bottom.

When I run the animation for a while, I start getting extra diagonal lines (and some diagonal lines even move) across the screen.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me why this is happening or how to fix it so there wouldn't be any extra diagonal lines.  Thanks.

```
int y = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1000,700);
  fill(235,185,155);
  rect(385,600,230,220);
  ellipse(500,350,600,600);
  fill(255,255,255);
  ellipse(400,290,100,100);
  ellipse(600,290,100,100);
  fill(0,0,200);
  ellipse(400,290,55,55);
  ellipse(600,290,55,55);
  fill(0,0,0);
  ellipse(400,290,20,20);
  ellipse(600,290,20,20);
}

void draw() {
  fill(0,0,0);
  rect(0,y,30,35);
  rect(100,y,30,35);
  rect(200,y,30,35);
  rect(300,y,30,35);
  rect(400,y,30,35);
  rect(500,y,30,35);
  rect(600,y,30,35);
  rect(700,y,30,35);
  rect(800,y,30,35);
  rect(900,y,30,35);
  rect(996,y,30,35);
  if (y <= 700) {
    y = y +1;
  }
}
```

Here is a link to a screenshot of what it looks like on my screen:
http://i1347.photobucket.com/albums/p708/lestillero/diagonallines_zpsagrou6dg.jpg

Comment: Please tag with the software library and/or programming language that you are using. Nobody will be able to answer unless you make it clear in what context we should read this.

Comment: I don't see any diagonal lines when I run your program. How long is a while? Can you take a screenshot of these diagonal lines?